# LXDE как устанавливать стандартные приложения?

Tags: debian, lxde

Как устанавливать стандартные приложения для LXDE? К примеру, как установить стандартным редактором текста *Gedit* (по умолчанию открывается *LibreOffice*) или как установить стандартным просмоторщиком изображений *Gwenview* (по умолчанию открывается *GIMP*)?

Единственное что я нашел для настройки стандартных приложений - это "приложения по умолчанию для LXSession", но настроить что-либо там не вышло.

Comment: вероятно, вы запустили какой-то gui-шный файловый «менеджер». какой именно? уточните это прямо в вопросе.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications